declare/set variables based on bool
I am trying to set some variables based on a bool in an if statement, but can't get it to work in a single if statement...
        if boating == true {
            var title = "Yacht Guru"
            var subtitle = "boat management, easier"
            var themeColor: Color = Color(hue: 0.617, saturation: 0.708, brightness: 0.842)
        } else {
            var title = "RV Guru"
            var subtitle = "RV management, easier"
            var themeColor: Color = Color(.green)
        }

I am trying to set a variable based on a variable.  This works, but I don't feel like its the best method...
//Is this boating or RV app?
let boating: Bool = false

struct MainView: View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        
        //Default text for the title and subtitle
        let title: String = {
            if boating == true {
                return "Yacht Guru"
            } else {
                return "RV Guru"
            }
        }()
        let subtitle: String = {
            if boating == true {
                return "boat management, easier"
            } else {
                return "RV management, easier"
            }
        }()
        let themeColor: Color = {
            if boating == true {
                return Color(hue: 0.617, saturation: 0.708, brightness: 0.842)
            } else {
                return Color(.green)
            }
        }()
        
        LogInView(themeColor: themeColor, title: title, subtitle: subtitle)
        
    }
}```


If this is really a whole app type thing it would be much simpler and efficient to just have a config file/struct. Even if it is only for section this is exactly why we use protocols and/or dependency injection

I would suggest using computed properties, defined outside the body of the view.
Other suggestions:

There is no need to compare a boolean value with true, just use as-is.
It is simpler to use ternary operators than if-else.
The body does not need to be explicitly tagged with @ViewBuilder, because this is automatic.

struct MainView: View {

    private var title: String {
        boating ? "Yacht Guru" : "RV Guru"
    }

    private var subtitle: String {
        boating ? "boat management, easier" : "RV management, easier"
    }

    private var themeColor: Color {
        boating ? Color(hue: 0.617, saturation: 0.708, brightness: 0.842) : .green
    }

    var body: some View {
        LogInView(themeColor: themeColor, title: title, subtitle: subtitle)
    }
}

However, if you really want to do it as you were asking in the question then you need to declare the variables outside of the if-else. They can be defined with let instead of var. So this works too:
var body: some View {
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let themeColor: Color
    if boating {
        title = "Yacht Guru"
        subtitle = "boat management, easier"
        themeColor = Color(hue: 0.617, saturation: 0.708, brightness: 0.842)
    } else {
        title = "RV Guru"
        subtitle = "RV management, easier"
        themeColor = .green
    }
    return LogInView(themeColor: themeColor, title: title, subtitle: subtitle)
}

Note that a return statement is now needed, because the body contains more than just view definitions.

You could try something simple using ternary directly, such as:
let boating: Bool = false

let title = boating ? "Yacht Guru" : "RV Guru"
let subtitle = boating ? "boat management, easier" : "RV management, easier"
let themeColor = boating ? Color(hue: 0.617, saturation: 0.708, brightness: 0.842) : Color(.green)


Another way is to initialize the properties in the initializer:
// Is this boating or RV app?
let boating: Bool = false

struct MainView: View {
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let themeColor: Color
    
    init(isBoating: Bool) {
        if isBoating {
            title = "Yacht Guru"
            subtitle = "boat management, easier"
            themeColor: Color = Color(hue: 0.617, saturation: 0.708, brightness: 0.842)
        } else {
            title = "RV Guru"
            subtitle = "RV management, easier"
            themeColor: Color = Color(.green)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        LogInView(themeColor: themeColor, title: title, subtitle: subtitle)   
    }
}

Notes:

@ViewBuilder is implicit
the properties do not need to be var

